# UE4 Import static mesh LODs

Tags: c++, import, unreal-engine4

Im very new to C++ in Ue4 ( been doing Blueprints for a couple of years and only Java /C# )

Im trying to find a way to create a way to import an entire folder with Both FBX LODs aswell as texture and assign them to a material.

the challenge looks like this.

I have a directory called: Flower 
In that directory i have files:

- Flower_LOD0.fbx
- Flower_LOD1.fbx
- Flower_LOD2.fbx
- Flower_Albeido.tar
- Flower_Opacity.tar
- Flower_Roughness.tar

  - etc.

I would like to be able to write a C++ function where i can specify the directory and it would create a static mesh, add the LODs and plug the textures into a new material instance of my mastermaterial.

Im not looking for a complete code for this, but maybe some help on the way when it comes to what classes and methods to use and the best approach. Since im more used to blueprints, im thinking that dividing each step into seperate functions and exposing them to blueprintCallable would be best for me? or is this simpler than i think? :)

Answer (score 0):

The FBX import process is rather complex and has tons of configuration options, so it will be a challenge to do this from code.

As a starting point, you should have a look at the API of the class `FFbxImporter` (`FbxImporter.h`), part of the implementation can be found in the file `FbxMainImport.cpp`.

You can also set a few breakpoints in `FbxFactory.cpp` and then try to import your FBX via the content browser.